# How to fix a wooden chair leg that was cracked?

Tags: furniture, wood-repair

I assume some super glue and a nail might hold it together?
[image]
[image]

Comment: wood glue and some screws

Comment: I'd suggest that this be migrated to [woodworking.se] as it's much more in their wheelhouse there. Also, no. Not super glue and a nail. Unless you don't like the person who sits in this chair.

Comment: This is a classic illustration of the disregard for suitable pieces of wood in factory-made furniture, especially in modern Asian-made factory furniture. This leg broke completely in two largely because of the poor grain direction in relation to the shape of the leg..... while you **can** glue it together very securely (good glue joints are literally stronger than the wood itself) consider that the wood above and below the existing break is *exactly* the same strength and could break in exactly the same way if stressed badly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No to super glue. You'll want to get a quality wood glue and wood screws at a minimum. I'd be looking at drilling in some dowel pins, maybe even sistering pieces of wood on either side of the crack. If this is "just a chair", you might want to just get a ne one. Why chance someone falling if it should fail again. It looks like a crack further up or is it just a scratch?

Comment: Thanks! We aren’t finding a replacement chair. Yes, the crack goes very far up.

Comment: Regarding the higher crack, that needs help as well. Sometimes you can suck wood glue into a crack with a shop vac on the other side.

Comment: You can also inject glue with a syringe